# Moderator tools / mobile app

Tags: support, feature-request

Are moderator tools available on mobile app (I'm using iOS)? If yes how do I access them? If no are there any plans for such?

Comment: I think it is best to access the site from full site. I have the mobile app for both android and iOS and it is horrible to peruse any of the SE sites with. This question is probably best asked if it hasn't already been asked on [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)